# PHP FTP_PUT on Windows IIS

Tags: php, iis, curl, ftp, server

Hoping there is an IIS PHP guru around...

I'm trying to use the standard FTP_PUT command in PHP with passive mode enabled, however I keep getting this error message:

Warning: ftp_put(): php_connect_nonb() failed: No such file or directory (2) in "....root to my script"

Yet, when I try the same script on an Apache server with a different host, it works perfectly! My IIS host says there is nothing their end which would block this, ie. firewall, transfer blocking, etc... Server is running: PHP 5.4.9 - FTP is enabled.

Tried the same script on another IIS server with a different host, PHP verison 5.3.28 - Same problem. Both hosts are baffled.

I've tried different ways to FTP in PHP, using CURL and file_put_contents - Still no joy!

Is there some sneaky configuration required in IIS to make PHP FTP just work!?? Please help...

**As requested... Here is my FTP code**

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpHOST);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpUSER, $ftpPASSWORD);

if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { //failed connection/login
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
} 
else {
    // try to upload file
    ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); //set passive mode
    if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $remoteFILE, $localFILE, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Successfully uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem while uploading";
    }
}
ftp_close($conn_id); // close the connection
```

Comment: Show us your code! Can you transfer files to the server using any other FTP (even GUI) client? Do you have access to the server log file?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - Sorry, code added to question. Please note, when it hits the FTP_PUT command, it fails with the error message in the question above. No access to FTP server logs...

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can FTP into the remote server with FireFTP client...

Comment: Show us FireFTP log.